# How can I set a Clean Aperture on a QuickTime file in ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am using ffmpeg to convert files to QuickTime containers. I understand that certain QuickTime files requires clap atoms, ie "This is a mandatory extension for all uncompressed Y´CbCr data formats."

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/QuickTime/QTFF/QTFFChap3/qtff3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000939-CH205-125850

Is there a way to specify a clap atom when using ffmpeg to output a QuickTime file? Otherwise would there be harm in adding a clap atom at the end of the file assuming that I updated any file length field? Lastly, assuming that there is not doubt as to the proper viewable/usable pixel dimensions of my file, is a clap even necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FFmpeg will write a `clap` atom if and only if the video codec is one of the following:

1. rawvideo pix_fmt uyvy422
2. rawvideo pix_fmt yuyv422
3. v308 (uncompressed packed 8-bit YUV 444)
4. v408 (uncompressed packed 8-bit YUV 4444)
5. v410 (uncompressed packed 10-bit YUV 444)
6. v210 (uncompressed packed 8 or 10-bit YUV 422)

So, if the codec qualifies, ffmpeg will automatically write it.

Comment: Is there benefit to having one if your content aspect ratio is the same as your file aspect ratio? As I understand, a clean aperture defines the visible part of the video frame, no?

Comment: If no cropping is needed, then it can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

I confirm that the latest version of FFMPEG writes a clap atom for a v210 video stream copied over to output Quicktime file, however it ignores the original input stream's CROPPED clean aperture value, and writes a (useless?) clean aperture value that simply equals the COMPLETE pixel dimensions.

If my QuickTime v210 input file is 720x486 with a clean aperture of 704x480... and video stream is simply copied to a new output file, output file will show 720x486 with a clean aperture of 720x486.